# Javascript: getAttribute throwing unexpected identifier when using custom attribute on custom element

Tags: javascript, html, custom-attributes, custom-element, getattribute

I keep getting an error on line 10 of this code where it defines Var x saying it is an unidentified identifier. I am trying to create my own custom element. When that custom element is in the HTML and has a country code, the console is to log this code. But it is not working for some reason. Can you help? Thank you!

```js
class FlagIcon extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._countryCode = null;
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["country"];
  }

  var x = this.getAttribute("country");
  console.log(x);

}

customElements.define("flag-icon", FlagIcon);
```

```html
<flag-icon country="hi">Hello</flag-icon>
```

Comment: It appears as though you're trying to run that code outside of any method or getter/setter, which is just not how classes work. Wrap it in a method call and call the method somewhere.

Comment: as for flag icons.. see: https://flagmeister.github.io

Answer (score 1):

Try doing that in connectedCallback() function

**Info:**

constructor() is called when the element is created.

connectedCallback() is called after the element is attached to the DOM.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Try running this snippet

```html
<script>
    class FlagIcon extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._countryCode = null;
    
  }
  connectedCallback(){
  var x = this.getAttribute("country");
    console.log(x);
  }
  static get observedAttributes() { return ["country"]; }
 }
 customElements.define("flag-icon", FlagIcon);

</script>

<html>
    <flag-icon country="hi">Hello</flag-icon>
</html>
```